# How can I add more space between points in recharts scatter graph?

Tags: reactjs, graph, space, recharts

I just want to add more space between the points. I know the prop `barCategoryGap` but I am using scatter and don't have this option.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To have more space between each points, you could simply have a bigger width for your graph; space between the points would adjust automatically to the new width.

You just need to update the `width` attribute on the ScatterChart component, like this:

```
<ScatterChart
  width={1000} // Use any width you want here, the bigger it is, bigger the gap will be between points
  height={400}
>
```